# python output string from server into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to convert a string such as below

```
str1='{"data":{"infostore":{"view":"infostore/split"},"mail":>>>{"auto_save_drafts":3,"select_first_message":true,"showname":false,"htmlmessage":true,"signatures":[],"view":"mail/hsplit/unthreaded","autocomplete":true,"formatmessage":"ALTERNATIVE","editor_featureset":2,"fullmailheader":true,"notifyacknoledge":true},"portal":{"externalcontents":[],"internalcontents":[{"module":"mail","visible":true,"external":false,"adj":{"y":0,"x":0},"params":{"limit":5},"header":"E-Mail"},{"module":"calendar","visible":true,"external":false,"adj":{"y":0,"x":1},"params":{"limit":5},"header":"Calendar"},{"module":"contacts","visible":false,"external":false,"adj":{"y":1,"x":2},"params":{"limit":5},"header":"Contacts"},{"module":"infostore","visible":true,"external":false,"adj":{"y":1,"x":0},"params":{"limit":5},"header":"InfoStore"},{"module":"tasks","visible":true,"external":false,"adj":{"y":1,"x":1},"params":{"limit":5},"header":"Tasks"}]},"global":{"minicalendar":{"expanded":false},"confirmpopup":true,"save":1,"autorefresh":10,"landing_page":{"module":"portal"}},"menu":{"menuiteration":2},"wizard":{"firstrun":false,"launchOnStart":false},"categories":{"local":[]},"effects":{"global":false,"hover":{"infostore":true,"mail":false,"speed":3,"portal":true,"tasks":true,"contacts":true,"calendar":true},"fading":false},"tasks":{"interval":30,"gridsort":"asc","view":"tasks/split"},"contacts":{"gridsort":"asc","cardsToViewPerColumn":"auto","view":"contacts/cards"},"calendar":{"workweek":{"countdays":5,"numberofappointments":2,"startday":1},"endtime":18,"autoadd_participant_public":true,"allfolders":true,"starttime":6,"default_reminder":15,"interval":30,"views":{"shared":true,"list":"workweek","team":"workweek","view":"calendar","calendar":"workweek"},"teamview":{"workingTimeOnly":true},"day":{"numberofappointments":4},"view":"calendar/calendar/workweek","custom":{"countdays":3,"numberofappointments":3}}}}'
```

into a dictionary ?

Comment: Try `ast.literal_eval(str1)`.

Comment: The formatting of the string isn't suitable to use that. (it was my first thouhgt). It has some character sequences which are invalid.

Comment: @mata submit that as an answer please! I will upvote it ;) It was definitely a typo so your solution works

Answer (score 2):

Did you copy that from a python interpreter session, or are the `>>>`s really part of the string?

If so, then this looks like json, so why not use [`json.loads()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json
str1 = ...
obj = json.loads(str1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should  remove the `>>>` and then use `json.loads()`

```
import json
str1 = str1.replace('>>>', '')
dict1 = json.loads(str1)
```

Otherwise you you also use `eval()`, but that wouldn't be a nice and safe solution.